# What is the Regression algo to Use for this case?

Tags: regression, spark-mllib

Having this Data :

```
clientId zipCode codeHeatingType countingType consumptionProfile householdCount squareFootage 

01       75015  ELEC            P012            A400            6               25              

02       75002  GAZ             P011            A600            3               30
```

and the AvgConsumtion

```
clientId     AvgConsumption
  01           300.5      (KWH)
  02           400        (KWH)
```

What machine learning to use to estimate the Avgconsumption depending on the client characteristics ? LogisticRegression ?, multilabel classification ?...

is it possible to have an exemple with string colums ?

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by "string column"?  How long are the strings? How many distinct values are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of regression to use depends mostly on the nature of the dependent variable.  Since your DV is continuous, you can start with OLS regression; it is certainly possible to have categorical independent variables.

You do have to look at the assumptions of OLS regression.

Comment: You mean that i can use a Linear Regression even if i had a String codes columns ?

Comment: In general, yes. There are limits, but yes, you can have a categorical IV in linear regression. It's done all the time.

Comment: so the idea is to map every String to an arbitrary INT and i should be able to train the model?

Comment: Any statistics program will dummy code categorical variables for you.

Comment: No i am a Java Developer, i want to choose the best learning machine and implement the Train and predict the consumption

Comment: I don't know anything about Java but this problem has been solved dozens of times by everyone who programmed any tool to do regression (SAS, SPSS, Matlab, Python, R, Lisp, Mathematica etc.)   It's probably been done in Java already, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: hi peter could you please help me with this question http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/240429/what-is-the-adequat-algorithm-for-similar-dependent-variables